# Angular - Changed image in server not reflecting in view

Tags: javascript, angularjs, caching, image-caching

I have an Angular application which shows people profile images(loaded from a server) and has an option to change it.

When the application loads the first time, the image is displayed properly. I call a web service to change the image on a server. The problem is even after changing the image on remote server, the image on the browser is not reflecting the change even on refreshing the page.

I tried using the meta tags to disable caching but it's not working for me.

The image changes on the browser only after I delete the browser cache. How can I solve this?

Example Flow based on Comments:

1. Initial path: `http://server_path/image_name.jpg`
2. Call web service and change the image (NOTE: path of image does not change. Only the
   image itself is replaced)
3. Refresh the page on browser

PROBLEM: Changed image not reflected.

Comment: Can you give an example perhaps? And most of the time that i've seen is that the HTML is not updated.

Comment: @Brendan The HTML code need not update since I'm not changing the file name on the server. The new image has the same name and path as the previous image. 

But still on refreshing the angular HTML page, the new image does not show up.

Comment: This sounds expected.  Did you check your network traffic?  I bet you get a 304 for the image call (if the image call even goes through).  Try adding a version to your image.  image.jpg?v123, and then increment that as the image changes...  or maybe pull it down in base64...  just some thoughts

Comment: does the file name of the image remain the same?

Comment: Yes. File name will be the same even after new image is uploaded.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If it is getting cached in the browser, you can force every request for the image to use a different URL, and so always request the server, by appending a different query string to it, say equal to the current number of milliseconds since 1970. A short custom directive is probably a good way:

```
app.directive('noCacheSrc', function($window) {
  return {
    priority: 99,
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      attrs.$observe('noCacheSrc', function(noCacheSrc) {
        noCacheSrc += '?' + (new Date()).getTime();
        attrs.$set('src', noCacheSrc);
      });
    }
  }
});
```

that is used as

```
<img no-cache-src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/5/51/Swallow_flying_drinking.jpg/320px-Swallow_flying_drinking.jpg">
```

(much as `ngSrc` would be used). You can see a [demo in this plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/t3mGF4Uwpanjy1JHTKJe?p=preview).

Note, the directive as written will probably not work if the `src` already has a query string. It might need to test for the presence of a `?` and adjust how it behaves (i.e. if there is a `?`, add `&` + seconds instead).

Edit: simplified by just using one directive.

Comment: Thanks! this is great as it actually works even when used in a loop!