# How to display a new image right away after successfully uploaded?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

[image]

I implemented a logo upload system. It would take effect right away. It require me to refresh the page to see the effect. I'm wondering how do I stop that.

## IMG

```
<img id="userLogo" src="/images/account/operator/logo.png" alt="" class="thumbnail img-responsive">
```

## Form

```
{!! Form::open(array('url' => '/profile/logo/update', 'class' => 'form-horizontal', 'role' =>'form','id' => 'editLogo','files'=>true)) !!}

<input name="logo_path" type="file"> <br><br>

 <button class="btn btn-success btn-sm mr5" type="file"><i class="fa fa-user"></i> Update Logo</button>

{{ csrf_field() }}
{!! Form::close();!!}
```

---

## Controller

```
public function updateLogo(){

    $inputs = Input::all();
    $logo_path = array('logo_path' => Input::file('logo_path'));

    $rule =  ['logo_path' => 'max:100|mimes:jpeg,bmp,png'];

    $id = Auth::user()->account_id;
    $type = Auth::user()->account_type;

    $validator = Validator::make($logo_path, $rule );

    if ( $validator->fails()) {
        return Redirect::to('/profile/')->withErrors($validator)->withInput();
    } else {

        $old_logo_path        = public_path().'/images/account/operator/logo.png';
        $delete = File::delete($old_logo_path);

        if (Input::hasFile('logo_path'))
        {

            $file            = Input::file('logo_path');
            $destinationPath = public_path().'/images/account/operator/';
            $uploadSuccess   = $file->move($destinationPath, 'logo.png');

        }

        return Redirect::to('/profile/')
        ->with('success','Your company logo was updated succesfully!');

    }
}
```

---

## Result

My file got saved to the place I want them to be. 
But when the old  logo is still showing on the page
unless, I refresh the page, then, I'll see my new one.

Any hints / suggestions on this will be much appreciated !

Comment: It's possible the browser has your logo cached. You'll need to generate a unique url for the logo. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23285280/angular-changed-image-in-server-not-reflecting-in-view

Comment: I was thinking about that, I usually stored them/receive them base on user account id. But in this case, I don't have the option to do that. If the operator change the main logo, it will show everywhere in the application, including the sign-in page.

Comment: I hope you have other suggestion for me.

Comment: append some random string as a querystring to the image source.. a date in milliseconds would be a nice option.

Comment: The link is very useful, but I wish it is in the Laravel or PHP. I don't have a lot of background in Angular.

Comment: `http://domain.com/someimagepath.jpg?q=34234234234`

Comment: Well, have a look at the question I linked. Like Vicky said, you can create a unique url by appending query strings. Oops, not sure why I linked to an angular question, I must have been confused, sorry. But the idea is the same.

Comment: So I will need to adjust my controller or my view ? I'm not sure.

Comment: Any further assistant on this will be great.

Comment: @VickyGonsalves : How do I integrate `q=34234234234` ? I see what you mean, but I am not sure exactly how to implement it. Where should I store that query number ?

Comment: please show the code where you rendered image

Comment: On the page where you are displaying the company logo, change the image source to something like .. <img src="/path/to/logo.png?<?php echo microtime(); ?>">

Comment: @VickyGonsalves: I update my post include - how I render my image.

Comment: Please check the answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because the image is cached in browser, and since you are updating an image with same name browser shows the already cached image. hence the better and effective solution is to have a unique file name every time you upload an image or you can append a querystring to the image path every time you serve an image.

```
<img id="userLogo" src="/images/account/operator/logo.png?q=<?php echo microtime(); ?>" alt="" class="thumbnail img-responsive">
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions/tips. Will great in my scenario.

Comment: The first time, it works, but if I do anything for a while, and tried to upload another logo. It cached to the old one again. It didn't work properly on the first time, but the second, third, and forth time.

Comment: Do you know why ? But yeah it's definitely better than before.

Comment: I will try it again in a couple mins, then, I will accept your answer.